# Renew certificate in Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: linux, nginx

I try to renew the SSL certificate in Nginx Proxy Manager
I added the certificate - it was accepted and shows in the control panel the right expiry date.
Then I changed it for a host.
But if I go to the site it shows still the old (expiting certificate)
Do I have to restart something?
On host or in NPM?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I came to the conclusion that the right certificate has to be also set up on the host.
Intially I set it up only on Nginx Proxy Manager.

After setting the very same certificate also on the host(s) it has begun to work properly.
I keep the question here for the case someone has the same question/problem

Comment: remember that you need to accept your solution. Else it will stay as unresolved for ever

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).